# DB migration: deleting a table

Tags: database-migration, flyway

What is the best practice for removing a database table when database upgrades are handled in 'migrations' fashion?

We use Flyway for database migrations.  Every time there is a database change, a migration script (which takes care of the delta change) gets added.

After a round of refactoring to remove obsolete code, couple of tables are no more needed.

Options I can think of are:

1. Leave those tables alone.  I don't like clutter, so prefer not to go with this option.
2. Add migration script to delete these tables.  Creating and later deleting a few tables will add to app installation time, again not preferable to us.
3. Edit one of the initial migration scripts, so the table doesn't get created for new installations.  Problem: Flyway will complain that one of the migrations was tampered with.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry so much about #2. The overhead is little when the tables are empty and it's not very often that one needs to rebuild the full DB anyway.